# Trying to figure out the function of small compartment

Tags: storage

I recently moved into a new flat and in my room I found a small space with a door. It has a horizontal opening on the upper and a smaller opening on the lower side and there are two pipe openings (cable trays?) on the inside (pictures attached). I have no idea what it is, can someone help me figure it out?

Thanks in advance!
-Jakob

[image: compartment closed]
[image: Door inside]
[image: Door inside lower closeup]
[image: "finger holes" inside]
[image: lower end inside]
[image: upper end inside]
[image: Door closed complete]

Comment: Those look like finger/hand grip to remove the whole panel removal

Comment: that looks like a cabling access panel (power and/or comms) ... the slots are for connecting cables to external devices ... the cabling equipment has been removed

Comment: Pics aren't great, but it could be an old electrical panel that's been gutted and abandoned for something more modern.

Comment: It was used for something in the past, but it was easier to leave the door as is, than to repair the wall.  One of the two guesses above is probably right.  Looks about the right size for some bottles of wine and some wine glasses, if you want to use it for something.  Don't tell the landlord or he might raise the rent.

Comment: A closer picture would help us figure this out better. A close up of the handle from the outside, the inside of the door, and the inside of the opening. Also, a closeup of one or both "hand holds" would help.

Comment: Yeah the picture quality was really bad, I added some new, better ones - hope it helps!

Comment: I would agree with those that say electrical panel  but only 2 holes? If that is a chase in the top back then it would make sense

Comment: Thank you to everybody for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access cover for (most likely) communications or electrical that either was never installed, or that has been removed after having been installed, presumably due to obsolescence. Removal rather than abandonment is uncommon in practice, so it may have been put in at the time of construction and never used for whatever its intended purpose was.

Unless the conduits/cable ducts happen to go somewhere it happens to be helpful for some thing you want to install, it's evidently irrelevant to your present occupancy.